# Google Ad Manager - Same line item serving all ad units on screen even though it doesn't have enough creatives

Tags: google-dfp, google-ad-manager

we have 3 same-size ad units set up that are being used both on our website and the Android app. The 3 ad units are being targeted by 3 line items. Each line item has 1 creative. So here is the setup:

line-item-1 (priority 6, single creative called creative-1)

- ad-unit-1
- ad-unit-2
- ad-unit-3

line-item-2 (priority 8, single creative called creative-2)

- ad-unit-1
- ad-unit-2
- ad-unit-3

line-item-3 (priority 10, single creative called creative-3)

- ad-unit-1
- ad-unit-2
- ad-unit-3

On the website, the behavior is as follows:

ad-unit-1 gets fulfilled by line-item-1 (creative-1), ad-unit-2 gets fulfilled by line-item-2 (creative-2), ad-unit-3 gets fulfilled by line-item-3 (creative-3). **This is the intended behavior as it results in no duplication of creatives.** Ad Manager smartly decides that since the highest priority line item doesn't have enough creatives to fulfill all ad units, it moves on to the lower priority line items..

On the Android app, the behavior is different and is as follows:

ad-unit-1, ad-unit-2 and ad-unit-3 ALL get fulfilled by line-item-1 (creative-1) thereby resulting in creative-1 being rendered 3 times on the screen. **This is an issue for us as we want the relatively lower priority line items to serve IF the higher priority one has run out of creatives.** It seems to work fine on web, but not on mobile app.

How do we deal with this? We don't want to complicate our Ad Manager set up to deal with this specific problem. My assumption is that if it works fine on web, we are probably missing a trick on the app side (how we fetch and render ads in our code maybe). We are using Play services (Ad Manager) to render ads. I went through the SDK methods but didn't find anything related to this issue.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting 3 ad units within the same line item. The only difference between the thee line item is the priority. If the price for this line item is also the same then most probably the three line items are in conflict with each other. Just based on one parameter you can't assume that the creatives should play as you assume. Price, size, resolution, device type and more importantly the DSP side matters a lot. It played as expected on web because of the device type. When it comes to mobile, the bid response structure from the DSP is different as it has additional parameters. This makes a lot of difference in the delivery.